# Finding volume enclosed by hyperboloid and plane $z = 2$ with double integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

[image]

I'm doing this problem andfor the highlighted second I had tried and thought it would be $\int r \,dz=zr$ so then evaluating at $\left.\vphantom{\dfrac 1 1}\right|^2_{\sqrt{r^2+1}}$ would give $2r - \sqrt{r^2+1}\,r$ can someone explain why the $r$ is only on the square root part in the second red boxed section.

Comment: It's obvioysly a typo, you can see that from the result of $6π$

Comment: Well, it seemed like it yes, but I've had a good share of times when I've thought that and it was just something I was missing or didn't know. So best to be sure that isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *typo* in the announced solution, we have
$$
\int^2_{\sqrt{r^2+1}} dz=\left[z\frac{}{}\right]^2_{\sqrt{r^2+1}}=2-\sqrt{r^2+1}
$$ giving
$$
\int^2_{\sqrt{r^2+1}} r\:dz=\left(2-\sqrt{r^2+1}\right)r
$$ as you have expected.